# Real world example for graph

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, analysis

Hi am a student of computer science. I need some real world example for graph to solve my assignment of analysis of algorithm(Data Structures). I couldn't find the perfect scenario for the real world graph application if you have any example in your mind please do tell me and guide me also in solution

Comment: Akram, if you have a smartphone, open maps. It is the best example of graph.

Comment: Nice idea @taurus. Thanks.

Comment: But the problem is that I have to create a question by self and solution also. What will be the question?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look at https://snap.stanford.edu/data/. This is a huge collection of network data sets from various sectors: social networks, road networks, etc.

Any network is, basically, a graph. You can ask a lot of research questions about these datasets. For example: what is the shortest way from X to Y (relevant for road graph)? who are the friends of someone (in social network)?

Good luck!